# water effect issue

Tags: modeling

I have watched many videos on how to make this exact drop thing, but my water flows out of the bowl it is supposed to stay in. I've even set the bowl as a domain, and it still flows thought the bowl as if it has cracks in it. This is just a simple example I set up to show I've used all the setting s the tutorials did, but my results are not like theirs.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just increase your resolution to 40 and you will get:

[image]

The resolution is very important because you can think of it as the "calculation precision" of the fluid. So higher it is, the better is the result. But of course the higher it is, the longer takes the simulation to calculate.